# How to get my own defined attribute value in my style

Tags: android, coding-style, resources, themes

I want to create 3 different themes for a dialog using a custom (own) attribute.
I would like to set title colors by adding this to theme's style:
`<item name="titleColor">#FF0000</item>`

my themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/dialog</item>
</style>
<style name="MyRedTheme" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="titleColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
<style name="MyGreenTheme" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="titleColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
<style name="MyBlueTheme" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="titleColor">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

I defined titleColor attribute in attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <declare-styleable name="MyCustomAttributes">
  <attr name="titleColor" format="color|reference" />
 </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I apply one of the themes for the dialog.
How can I pass my titleColor attribute's value to an "android:color" attribute?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.dicare"
   android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="I want to pass titleColor value here"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Refer this link,You can get more idea about using custom xml attributes.[HERE](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/android-custom-xml-attributes-and-views/)

Comment: I would like to insert value defined by my custom attribute not to extend a view component with a new attribute

Comment: I have the same problem. Still haven't found any solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

?titleColor [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)

or

You'd define your colours in the colors.xml file and reference them like a normal resource: @color/MyRed

You'd make a custom attribute for your own views which you want to be customisable from layout xmls. For example, you might extend TextView to write the first line of text in one colour (titleColor) than the rest of the text (android:textColor).

```
<color name="MyRed">#FF0000</color>

<style name="MyRedTheme" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="titleColor">@color/MyRed</item>
</style>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.dicare"
   android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@color/MyRed"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: well "?" should solve the problem, but it gives me an:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2

Comment: I have the same problem. Still haven't found any solution.

Comment: Why is this solution accepted. Do it answer the question how to access own color defined in style?

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing that you will have to do is edit your attrs.xml file. Here you will add all of the attributes that you want to define via xml.  Here we have added a title, as well as right and left buttons with text and a drawable.

```
<declare-styleable name="activity_header">
    <attr name="title" format="string" />               

    <attr name="left_button_text" format="string" />
    <attr name="left_button_drawable" format="reference" />

    <attr name="right_button_text" format="string" />
    <attr name="right_button_drawable" format="reference" />

    <attr name ="hide_buttons">
        <enum name="yes" value="1" />
        <enum name="no" value="0" />
    </attr>                        
</declare-styleable>
```

Next you'll want to create your layout.  The important thing here is to add a namespace that refers to your app.  Here I have named it app.  You just need to include your package name after http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ .  Now you can use any of the attributes you defined above in your xml file.

<

```
LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.biggu.shopsavvy.ui4"  
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      >


<com.biggu.shopsavvy.ui4.ActivityHeader 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
    android:id="@+id/header"
    app:title = "History"                                  

    app:left_button_text="Share"
    app:left_button_drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_share" 

    app:right_button_drawable="@drawable/small_btn_archive"
    app:right_button_text="Organize"   />
```

Now that we have our attributes defined in our xml file we need to retrieve them from our custom component that we have made.  You should simply have to get the obtained style attributes using your resource that you created, here we used activity_header.

```
  public class ActivityHeader extends LinearLayout {

    TextView mTitleEditText;
    Button mLeftButton;
    Button mRightButton;

    View mDelimeter;
    private ViewGroup mAdditionalPanel;



    public ActivityHeader(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);      
        ViewGroup.inflate(context, R.layout.header , this);             

        findViews();

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.activity_header);      

        if ( a.getInt(R.styleable.activity_header_hide_buttons, 0) == 1) //hide buttons
        {
            mLeftButton.setVisibility(GONE);
            mRightButton.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            setLeftButtonDrawable(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.activity_header_left_button_drawable, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details));      
            setLeftButtonText(a.getString(R.styleable.activity_header_left_button_text));                       

            setRightButtonDrawable(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.activity_header_right_button_drawable, android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details));                    
            setRightButtonText(a.getString(R.styleable.activity_header_right_button_text)); 
        }


        setTitle(a.getString(R.styleable.activity_header_title));                                                                                         
        a.recycle();        
    }
}
```

That's it. Happy coding.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the point is how to use theme attributes at different places, not how to use custom attributes in custom views :)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is change the android:color for custom:color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.dicare"
   android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid custom:color="I want to pass titleColor value here"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I would like to insert value defined by my custom attribute not to extend a view component with a new attribute