# How to get(reference) the current theme default text color in XML

Tags: android, resources, themes

I have a shape (*rect_shape.xml*) which draws a stroke outline in every item of a listview (*listview_style.xml*).
This outline should have the same color like the default text color of the current theme.

Is there any way, **in XML**, to set the android:color value of the stroke to the current text color?

I've seen some similar questions (like [How to get my own defined attribute value in my style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271329/how-to-get-my-own-defined-attribute-value-in-my-style) ) around here which try to set an own attribute, but I don't think that this is what I want.
Anyhow I tried that but I couldn't set the android:color value to my own defined attribute ( `android:color="?custom_stroke_color"` throws InflateException).

Because the user is able to switch between the Themes dynamically, one single predefined color (or reference to a color resource e.g. `@color/white` ) in *rect_shape.xml* is not an option.

Appreciate any help...

**rect_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke android:width="3dp"
<!-- should be the current default text color -->
    android:color="#FFF" />

<solid/> 
...
</shape>
```

**listview_style.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rect_shape" >
...
</LinearLayout>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
<!-- default text color is white -->
...
</style>
<style name="LightTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<!-- default text color is black-->
...
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing themed attributes in drawable XML files is only available in android 5.0 and up.

See [This issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251)