# Android different textview with different rounded edges and colors background

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-shape

I am using a large number of textviews across my android app. And I have a background.xml file with shape and color property of rounded edges. I set this background to my textview. If I have a few different colors as background, I can create seperate background xmls. What if I have more than 30 or 40 different colors to be used, should I have as many background files ?

Comment: no, use Drawable.setColorFilter

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain single background files and create all stying attribute for your text view like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
      <style name="style_1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
          <item name="android:textColor">#FFA500</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">#FFA500</item>
      </style>

      <style name="style_3" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
          <item name="android:textColor">#FFA500</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">#FFA500</item>
      </style>

      <style name="style_n" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
          <item name="android:textColor">#FFA500</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">#FFA500</item>
      </style>
  </resources>
```

For styling please refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Can I add the shape attribute inside style ?

Comment: You can create common drawable for shape and use in Style. ref this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271329/how-to-get-my-own-defined-attribute-value-in-my-style

Answer (score 1):

you can use PaintDrawable with Dynamic color in Java code like below.

```
 final TextView hint = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_hint);
        hint.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        PaintDrawable paintDrawable1=new PaintDrawable(getRandomColor());
        paintDrawable1.setCornerRadius(20f);
        hint.setBackground(paintDrawable1);

private int getRandomColor(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(56), rnd.nextInt(256));
}
```